# Optional parameters when using AWS CLI to launch CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a CloudFormation template that'll deploy a Lambda function,  And I need the security options to be optional parameters.

I was able to partially accomplish this using the question here:

[How to make a whole object in CloudFormation templates optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933841/how-to-make-a-whole-object-in-cloudformation-templates-optional)

Interestingly, that method worked great to make the VpcConfig property optional in the AWS GUI Console, but it did NOT work to make it optional for the CLI.  And unfortunately, I need it to work in the CLI, since I'll be using CodeBuild to call and deploy this template's resources.

Here are the relevant parameters:

```
"SecurityGroupIds" : {
   "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
   "Description" : "A list of one or more security groups IDs in the VPC that includes the resources to which your Lambda function requires access."
 },
 "SubnetIds" : {
   "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
   "Description" : "A list of one or more subnet IDs in the VPC that includes the resources to which your Lambda function requires access."
 }
```

And conditions:

```
    "HasVPC": {"Fn::And": [{"Fn::Not": [{"Fn::Equals": [{"Fn::Join": ["", {"Ref": "SubnetIds"}]}, ""]}]}, {"Fn::Not": [{"Fn::Equals": [{"Fn::Join": ["", {"Ref": "SecurityGroupIds"}]}, ""]}]}]}
```

And here's where that condition is used in the Lambda resource being defined in the Resources section of the template:

```
"VpcConfig": {
  "Fn::If": [
    "HasVPC",
    {
      "SecurityGroupIds" : {"Ref": "SecurityGroupIds"},
      "SubnetIds" : {"Ref": "SubnetIds"}
    },
    { "Ref":"AWS::NoValue" }
  ]
},
```

When I issue the command to deploy this stack in the CLI, I get the following error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet
>   operation: Parameters: [SecurityGroupIds, SubnetIds] must have values

Here's the AWS CLI command I'm issuing, from the same directory in which the template is located.  Note: the ARN values have all been heavily modified to not be real values from my account, but I kept them in the right format so you can see the real format of the command:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file lambda-template.json --stack-name "CLI-lambda-stack" --parameter-overrides S3BucketName="myBucket" S3FileLocation="lambda_function.zip" S3ObjectVersion="ZuB0iueEghOyh5q00.DiykLNudujdsc5" DeadLetterArn="arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:577898337216:CloudFormationTests" EnvironmentVariable="testing" KmsKeyArn="arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:504398934246:key/b24e7b72-a94d-6a3e-b848-165115c86212" HandlerFunctionName="lambda_function.lambda_handler" MemorySize="128" Role="arn:aws:iam::102893937243:role/serverless-test-default-us-east-1-lambdaRole" FuncName="myCLILambda"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing `SecurityGroupIds` neither `SubnetIds` default values and your are not providing them on your `--parameter-overrides`. Therefore, CloudFormation doesn't know how to process them if no values are provided.

Adding the `Default` statement should do the trick:

```json
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "SecurityGroupIds" : {
      "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Description" : "A list of one or more security groups IDs in the VPC that includes the resources to which your Lambda function requires access.",
      "Default" : ""
    },
    "SubnetIds" : {
      "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
      "Description" : "A list of one or more subnet IDs in the VPC that includes the resources to which your Lambda function requires access.",
      "Default" : ""
    }
}
```

Comment: When I said "parameter list", I meant your `--parameter-overrides` parameter on CLI command. I edited my answer (after accepting your edit) to make it more clear.